# conectar una aplicación de vb.net a un web service

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webservice, visual-studio-2013

Soy nuevo en el manejo de web service, y tengo un problema, realice una aplicación que me genera un archivo comprimido, este archivo se tiene que enviar a una dirección ip, un servidor en otro estado, como es que mi aplicación le envié el archivo al web service y que este lo guardara en la ruta destino, los tutoriales que he visto son algo confusos y la mayoría esta en C#, mi proyecto esta en VB .net, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Que tal @El fercho, puedes compartir parte del código donde haces el guardado.
Y en sí cuál es tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Es lo mismo:
 1. Buscar la opción de referencia de servicios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Añades la dirección del web services y pulsas "Aceptar"
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Luego, desde una clase, haces la instancia del objeto creado
   `Private PR_Servi As New ServicesReference1.Service1SoapClient`, y por último
4. Crear los métodos de tu clase según la funcionabilidad de los métodos de tu web services. Por ejemplo:

   Public Function AccionUpdate(ByVal Opcion As Integer) As Boolean
       Try
           PR_Servi.ActualizaOpciones(PrOpcion)
           AccionUpdate= True
       Catch ex As Exception
           Dim st As New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()
           Bitacora_Error(Err.Number, ex.Message, myType.Name,st.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, False)
           AccionUpdate= False
       End Try
   End Function

Ya, dentro de la progamación de tu aplicación instancias esta clase y listo. Ejemplo:

```
Dim ws As New ClsWebServices
dim correcto_bool as Boolean 
correcto_bool = ws.AccionUpdate(1)
```